# C# Web Server for displaying Console Output?

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, webserver, embeddedwebserver

I have just finished writing my c# console application, and I am contemplating embedding a web server into it (probably this one http://webserver.codeplex.com). I don't do much in the way over advanced web coding though, so I am not sure if I can do what I need to.

Basically, I would like to allow users to view the console output of my application in realtime just by visiting the site being served by my application. If I understand correctly, to do something like this it would require AJAX, which a simple C# Web Server wouldn't be able to handle.

Is this correct or is there an easy way to do this I am missing?

Comment: You don't need AJAX in order to refresh a html page periodically. It depends on how often the console output changes.

Comment: Oh, did you consider a self-hosted Full Duplex WCF service and a silverlight application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to re-route console output**

You will need to write your own `TextWriter` and make `Console` use it via `Console.SetOut`. This writer should notify connected web clients, as well as the original `Console.Out`.

**How to host a COMET-like server**

You can use `HttpListener` and some basic async programming to do this. If you wrap the `HttpListenerContext.Response.OutputStream` in a `StreamWriter` (with `AutoFlush` set to `true`) and set `HttpListenerContext.Response.SendChunked` to `true` clients will receive partial results - this means you can even do it in an IFRAME.

You will need to add rights to the URL for yourself if UAC is enabled:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:9090/ user=domain\username
```

**Code?**

I couldn't resist it; I have written a (poorly tested and mostly incomplete) [sample](https://gist.github.com/1167986).

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! I look forward to checking this out :)

Comment: Its not working with log4Net. I have read the source code of the appender and its using 'Console.Write(...)', but Console.SetOut(this); & Console.SetError(this); only listens on local app Console.Write. Any idea how to solve this? Maybe translate your code into an Log4Net Appender. The world could be so easy...

Answer (score 0):

That is incorrect.

AJAX is a client side technique relying on JavaScript. As long as the web server can respond to an HTTP request, it can server *AJAX content* (whatever that might mean:-).

Answer (score 0):

I would use this [UtilDev Cassini](http://ultidev.com/products/cassini/) as me embedded web server of choice, it is based on the code from the embedded Visual Studio dev server and can run pretty much anything that runs in IIS.  AJAX is a browser technology not a server technology, the server just sees http requests the same as any other.  My last point would that it seems slightly odd to embed a web server in a console application.  It would be more usual to do this with a windows service.  Have you considered converting the console app into a windows service?

Comment: Just to note, my application is ran as a windows service. I didn't go into the full details to keep the question short, but the reason for the webpage is because the user never sees the console.